# Meteor device detection android or ios?

Tags: meteor, device-detection

I have an meteor app that is deployed for both ios and android device and i want certain code to run on only ios device and not on android. I know that I can detect device using meteor device-detection package like

```
Meteor.Device.isPhone()
```

But is there any possible way can know if its an android or iOS device.

EDIT: I have created bundle using meteor cordova.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a global helper that should do the trick as far as detecting iOS:

```
Template.registerHelper('isIOS',() => {
  return ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false );
});
```

And another for Android:

```
Template.registerHelper('isAndroid',() => {
  return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1;
});
```

To use anywhere in client js:

```
Blaze._globalHelpers.isIOS()
Blaze._globalHelpers.isAndroid()
```

And of course, to use in html template markup:

```
{{#if isIOS}}...{{/if}}
{{#if isAndroid}}...{{/if}}
```

Comment: u have used indexof for android and match for ios does that makes any differnce

Comment: Not really - Android is simpler since it only comes in one flavor. iOS comes in 3.

Comment: this only works for broswer but what if i have created bundle using meteor cordova

Comment: Sorry to necro, but how would one do this within react?

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32416003/2805154) should help you with React. Just define the functions and export them, then require them in your jsx.