# Device detection if is android?

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, device-detection

I have an meteor app that is deployed for both ios and android device and i want certain code to run on only ios device and not on android. I know that I can detect device using navigator.userAgent but this will only work if i have my app running on browser.

**//This works if its a browser**

```
navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1;
```

But is there any possible way to detect device if i have created bundle for android using meteor cordova plugin so it works like a native app.

Comment: Did you try Device API? You can check if(device.platform == 'Android')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor device detection android or ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076642/meteor-device-detection-android-or-ios)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Nijil Nair suggested use the  [Cordova Device Plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html) . If you need help adding the plugin see [Meteor Cordova](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration) . Once the plugin is properly installed you can use `var devicePlatform = device.platform;` which will return one of the following based on the device:

- "Android"
- "BlackBerry"
- "iOS"
- "WinCE"

Comment: Meteor Cordova link has moved to: https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#introduction

Comment: Not all versions of Windows return `WinCE`, check [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html#deviceplatform) out for more.

Comment: From the recent code documentation: ` /**
     * The device platform (lowercase).
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    platform: 'ios' | 'android' | 'web';`

Answer (score 35):

No reason for plugins, just use window.

```
window.cordova.platformId
```

You can also get the version of the os.

Full output:

> window.cordova.platformId
>
> "android"
>
> window.cordova.platformVersion
>
> "7.0.0"

Comment: Where is the documentation of this field? How to check what values are possible?

Comment: Is this safe to use? Can we rely on this?

Comment: @PlsWork It is safe to use. A freshly created Cordova project has this line: `console.log('Running cordova-' + cordova.platformId + '@' + cordova.version);` Check the `cordova-app-hello-world` package. Also search your Cordova project's "platforms" folder for "platformId: platform.id" and you'll see it in the various platforms, e.g. android/platform_www/cordova.js or ios/www/cordova.js