# Meteor and React: Helpers

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I've been looking into moving from Blaze to React as the frontend for my Meteor apps. I can't seem to find is equivalent of *helpers* in Blaze which use `UI.registerHelper`

`UI.registerHelper` in Blaze allows you to setup globally accessible helpers that can be used across any template.

A typical example might be a helper that transforms an ISO Date into a human readable date format.

From what I can see, React Classes can have their own properties which can be functions that perform helper-like tasks. But what I can't see is how you create them on a global level.

How is this achieved in when using React in Meteor?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the reactivity of a helper, since a change in the DB will trigger a change in the meteor mixin, thus trigging a change in your `render()`.  So, all you need is a global function.

`file: formatDate.jsx`

```
module.exports = function(dateStr) {
  return new Date(dateStr);
}
```

then at the top of your component:

`let formatDate = require('./formatDate.jsx')`

Comment: thanks for explaining re: reactivity. I totally get that. Couple of Qs:  Does the usage of `require('./formatDate.jsx')` come natively with Meteor or React? And is this method common to Meteor or React? Sorry if this sounds daft I just want to be using recommended techniques.

Comment: `require` is the standard for commonjs, which was adopted by node. it comes with react (Meteor breaks it by default in favor or their own package system, not sure how). In place of require you could use ES2015 module syntax with webpack, but that's trickier.

Comment: This is changing as we speak. The Meteor 1.3 release goes a long way towards interoperability with NPM, and lets you use "require" directly: 

https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-3-early-beta-now-available/14723

On topic; Because react puts the view inside the javascript file, you have direct access to any type of "helper" that you'd previously use in Meteor + Blaze. I think this (Matt K) answer is correct in that sense. Just access anything you want of your javascript code in react by using single curly braces {} and referring to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used react before. although in meteor, I think setup globally accessible helpers is not a good way to solve this problem, because it may pollute app namespace.

So I always use some module loader, like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/), to define your useful helpers function as a `util` module and require it in your other code.

I wish this general solution could help you :-)

Comment: I'm fairly certain `UI.registerHelper` is the preferred method for helper sharing across Blaze Templates. In the [Blaze Docs](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/docs.html#ui_registerhelper) it says _Defines a helper function which can be used from all templates._

I wonder what harm you could cause by having lots of helpers and polluting it's namespace?